# 80s/90s live-action TV show with flying suits

Tags: story-identification, tv

It was a sci-fi show with real actors that I believe had accompanying toys, if that helps. Late 80s / early 90s.

It was some futuristic Robocop kinda stuff, with a flying suit contraption that looked more like the robot Ripley used in Aliens. The device closed around them in the same way, kind of like how roller coasters do where the bar closes over your body.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! This question is a bit terse at the moment, could you take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: So was it something similar to the jetpacks used in [Captain Scarlet](https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/323763767534_/CAPTAIN-SCARLET-50-YEARS-Card-26.jpg)?

Comment: It was more of a small flying contraption that wasn't any bigger than a suit. I think it starred some ex-NFL guy or bodybuilder in one of the roles. Saturday morning stuff, but not a cartoon.

Answer (score 5):

You provide very little detail so it's hard to be certain but what you describe could feasibly be [*Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future). It was live action featured suits in line with what you describe and yes, there was a tie-in line of toys. Also your timeframe is a good match.

Comment: The time frame is close, but the suits don't match. They flew. These were more like robot vehicles than suits. It was a cage that locked the pilot in and they stood vertically kinda like the robot from Aliens.

Comment: @SonnyListon it couldn't possibly be Photon could it? It's a partial match for what you describe but seems like a long shot.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P66m5cF2BJo

Comment: Wow, that show brings back memories. It's not that show. It has a more bombed out ubran decay aesthetic from Robocop. It's not really a suit, it's more of a vehicle that is slightly larger than the body that you strap into. Think the Aliens power loader but without the forks/arms.  https://news.toyark.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2015/09/Aliens-Power-Loader-001.jpg